# how to return a colomn value from only one row

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I use this code to put a picture from a table into a div animated with jquery as a slideshow but the problem that i need only on picture and not all pictures in the same time ? what can i do ? 
the code :

```
    <?php
    require_once 'includes/connect.php';

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT userPic FROM AddOffer WHERE id_user=:id ORDER BY id_user DESC');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetchColumn())
        {
            extract($row);
    ?>

    <img src="user_offers/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" class="img-roundeds" width="200px" height="200px" />     
    <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <span> Ajouter une Photo à votre Profil</span>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: look into using pagination with a LIMIT of 1.

Comment: And learn to use `sprintf` or better template engine to clean up code.

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT 1 to your SQL

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT userPic FROM AddOffer WHERE id_user=:id ORDER BY id_user DESC LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: and what about the rest of their images; how are they going to show the rest of them? [I believe I answered that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441760/how-to-return-a-colomn-value-from-only-one-row#comment62386134_37441760), just not the complete code for it ;-)

Comment: I have a jquery slideshow and i want to call to the images from the table

Comment: To me question looked like it was for limiting rows from a SQL query. Might be best just to start a new question about jquery and javascript and ajax.

Comment: the jquery code is correct and the slide is build correctly with a fixed images .. and i want to transform the fixed images to a called images form a date table